What's the value of $\int \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} dx$?
Motivation: This was a printing error in my MCQ test, correct question contained the first order derivative. But it's destroying my mental peace.
My attempt
I don't even know where to start. This looks so utterly simple yet it isn't.
Only thing I could do is
Let $y=f(x)$.
So $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)}{dx} 
\implies d^2 y \ dx =d\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg) dx^2$$
How to proceed anywhere from here?

You cannot proceed on your current path, as I explained why here

@NinadMunshi thanks for that. If I correct my path now, still will I be able to get a closed form solution?

If $f\propto\exp\int gdx$ so $f'=gf$ your integral becomes $\int(g^{\prime\prime}+g^{\prime2})dx$, but the second term is intractable in general.

apparently MCQ   means multiple choice questions

@WillJagy yessir. But it wasn't the original question, it was a typo. Original answer had the usage of $\ln f(x)$ to solve a logarithmic sum

I don't think you will get a nice formula, However, you can try: $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx=1/x$. Apply the derivative to both side and manipulate the terms until you get to your desired form. The R.H.S will not be necessarily simpler to integrate.

@NoChance would you like to show your manipulation as an answer? I can't bring it to my desired form. Whatever I do to $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ it stays the same. Double differential just cancels out

OK, but the result on the R.H.S will not be an integral that can be evaluated analytically. I mean we will end-up with difficult form=difficult form, is this something you are interested in?

Hi @Gwen, what if we did this - $\int \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} dx=\int \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}\cdot\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)},dx$ and maybe try out IBP or something..
